# Помогите понять в чём проблема HTML Flash

Tags: html, flash, embedded, swf

Есть блок `<embed>` на сайте. Я скопировал его себе и всё прекрасно работает.

```html
<div>
  <embed height="1"
      flashvars="game_server=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shararam.ru%2F&amp;url_path_server=https%3A%2F%2Fsharaball.ru%2F&amp;portal_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shararam.ru%2F&amp;start_step=0&amp;manual_server_selection=&amp;domainId=0&amp;useHashInName=true&amp;splcid=SP1131125360&amp;client=0"
      pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
      src="https://sharaball.ru/base.swf?v=87" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      width="1"
      quality="high"
      align="center"
      id="base"
      bgcolor="#ffffff"
      name="base"
      menu="true"
      allowfullscreen="true"
      allowscriptaccess="always"
      style="height: 335.156px; width: 551.823px;">
</div>
```

Я скачал ресурс "https://sharaball.ru/base.swf?v=87" и сохранил как *D:/Downloads(D)/base.swf*, и пытаюсь использовать его вместо оригинальной ссылки, но он начинает неправильно работать. Как я понимаю не передаются значения из `flashvars`.

То есть вот мой код:

```html
<div>
  <embed height="1"
      flashvars="game_server=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shararam.ru%2F&amp;url_path_server=https%3A%2F%2Fsharaball.ru%2F&amp;portal_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shararam.ru%2F&amp;start_step=0&amp;manual_server_selection=&amp;domainId=0&amp;useHashInName=true&amp;splcid=SP1131125360&amp;client=0"
      pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
      src="D:/Downloads(D)/base.swf" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      width="1"
      quality="high"
      align="center"
      id="base"
      bgcolor="#ffffff"
      name="base"
      menu="true"
      allowfullscreen="true"
      allowscriptaccess="always"
      style="height: 335.156px; width: 551.823px;">
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я рекомендую не тратить на мёртвую технологию время. Только последний сайт типа mail.ru не забанил Flash. Поэтому и им не стоит пользоваться.

Comment: @0andry чесно говоря, меня не волнует актуален или нет флеш, мне нужно решить поставленную задачу